# Access variables declared inside JavaScript switch statement from outside

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, switch-statement, javascript-scope

Why does

```
switch ("string") {
  case "string":
    const text = "Hello World!"
    break
}

console.log(text)
```

return `error: Uncaught ReferenceError: text is not defined` ?

I don't understand why the variable text returns undefinded.

Comment: As you know `const` is block scoped. Since you have the brackets around the `switch`, `const` won't be accessible outside them. However, you can delcare a `let` outside and assign its value inside the `case` statement

Comment: You have just stumbled on what a scoped variable is. Just so you can play around, create the variable text outside the switch, and set its value inside the switch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it is not in the same scope. Something like this should work:

```
let text
switch ("string") {
  case "string":
    text = "Hello World!"
    break
}

console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 1):

Declaring a variable with const is similar to let when it comes to Block Scope.

The x declared in the block, in this example, is not the same as the x declared outside the block:

```
var x = 10;
// Here x is 10
{ 
  const x = 2;
  // Here x is 2
}
// Here x is 10
```

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_const.asp